# Search By Time (only) in DateTime SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working with SQL Server & PHP and using stored procedures.

I have a table called `myTable`. I has a column `start_time` (DateTime Format).

```
start_time
-----------------------
2019-05-23 12:20:22.000
2019-08-02 01:21:02.000
2019-02-10 22:32:17.000
2019-08-14 04:56:24.000
```

I want to filter results by time only.

> For-example: **BETWEEN** 22:20:10.000 **AND** 04:56:24.000

But, It's not Working.

Comment: where is the code that is not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple casting to `time` datatype will work:

```
select * from myTable
where cast(start_time as time) >= '22:00:00.000'
   or cast(start_time as time) <= '04:00:00.000'
```

Note that applying a `CAST` function to the `start_time` column in the `WHERE` clause predicate will prevent an index that column from being used efficiently. A full table scan will be required unless other criteria are specified.

Comment: `AND`, not `OR`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov `AND` would return no results :) As ranges are exclusive and no time woul satisfy condition with `AND`.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that the range goes across midnight. Sorry.

Comment: When you see the solution it seems so obvious but... +1

Comment: Note that applying a `CAST` function to the `start_time` column in the `WHERE` clause predicate will prevent an index that column from being used efficiently. A full table scan will be required unless other criteria are specified.

Comment: @DanGuzman I pasted your remark into my answer :) thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

this code will work please check

```
create table #temp
(
[Date] datetime
 )


insert into #temp  values ('2019-05-23 12:20:22.000')
insert into #temp  values ('2019-08-02 01:21:02.000')
insert into #temp values ('2019-02-10 22:32:17.000')
insert into  #temp  values  ('2019-08-14 04:56:24.000')

 select cast([Date] as date) as [Date],convert(char(15), [Date], 108) [Time]  
 from #temp
 where convert(char(15), [Date], 108) between '04:56:24' and '22:32:17'

 Drop table #temp
```

[image]